# What farmable items produces the most gems

Tags: growtopia

I want to make as much money as possible. Buying stuff and selling it takes time because I don't have vending machine.

Time to harvest doesn't matter. I don't mind waiting.

Comment: Time to harvest should be taken into account, it’s pretty useful in knowing how much time it takes to grow with lots of gems versus with little amount of gems. For example, something might give 20 gems a block, but takes two weeks to grow, unlike something that gives 5 gems a blow, but only takes 5 hours to grow.

Answer (score 2):

Chandeliers are the farmable that gives you the most gems, but the chandelier is hard to break, you can break laser grids faster but less gems, whichever you prefer, more gems or more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The farmable that gives the most gems is magic bells. However, farming this is a pretty bad option as it takes over nine days to grow, making it remarkably inefficient. I recommend opting for Laser Grids. Laser Grids take about 3 — 4 days. Laser Grids are also significantly more expensive than Pepper Trees.

Also, I know you don’t care about the wait time, however, even though laser grids do give less gems than chandeliers and magic bells, the waiting time is what makes the laser grid give more gems than the other two, because it is 2x and 3x less wait, and the laser grids give just a little bit less per a block, so I would say grids are the right choice.